# JPA with Hibernate: findDirty not taken into account for new child entities - bug or feature?

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

We are currently facing an 'issue' with new entities and the findDirty interceptor - and from our perspective it looks like a bug. However it might be also a feature - thus expertise and comments on this topic is appreciated.

Cheers
Christoph

Our environment:
Hibernate 4.2.7 (using JPA API 2.x)

**The issue:**
We have two entities UserBO and InternalOrganizationBO
The relationsship between the two objects is shown below.
Both objects have a boolean flag 'flushUpdates'.
This 'flushUpdate' flag is evaluated in our custom findDirty implementation (overwrite of EmptyInterceptor.findDirty).
If 'flushUpdate' is false the findDirty returns an empty array.

**What we are doing:**
1. We get the UserBO object from the database (thus in managed state)
2. We create a new InternalOrganizationBO object
3. We set the flushUpdates flag for the UserBO and InternalOrganizationBO to false
4. We set the InternalOrganizationBO object for the User
5. Call the entityManager.flush method

**What we think is a bug:**
The entityManager.flush method is triggering a SQL INSERT for the InternalOrganizationBO
ALTHOUGH the findDirty method returns for both objects an empty array AND we didn't
call an explcit persist for the InternalOrganizationBO.

(By the way: the 'findDirty' seems to work fine when both objects are already in the database and in a managed stated)

**So the questions:**
Is this really how the Hibernate framework should behave?
Shouldn't the 'empty array' returned from findDirty prevent an insert?
Are there other options to prevent Hibernate to do the insert?

--- Source Code Entity Classes:

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(....)
@Table(schema="...", name="...")
@IdClass(UserBO_PK.class)
public class UserBO  extends AbstractBO  implements Serializable  {
 ...
 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH,    CascadeType.PERSIST})
 @JoinColumn(name=UserBO.INTERNALORGANIZATION_ID)
 protected InternalOrganizationBO internalOrganization;
 ...
 @Transient
 protected boolean flushUpdates = false;

  public boolean isFlushUpdates() {
   return flushUpdates;
  }
  ...
}    


@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="InternalOrganizationBO",
    entities = @EntityResult(entityClass=InternalOrganizationBO.class),
    columns = { @ColumnResult (name="externalName")})
@Table(schema="...", name="...")
@IdClass(InternalOrganizationBO_PK.class)
public class InternalOrganizationBO  extends AbstractBO implements Serializable  {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="internalOrganization", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    protected List<UserBO> users;

   ...
    @Transient
    protected boolean flushUpdates = false;

    public boolean isFlushUpdates() {
        return flushUpdates;
    }
   ...
}
```

--- SourceCode TestCase
    //load user objects
    UserBO user = entityManager.find(UserBO.class, new UserBO_PK("testUser"));

```
//create internal organization
intOrg01 = new InternalOrganizationBO(intOrg01_id);
intOrg01.setCode(intOrg01_code);
intOrg01.setBusinessUnit(BusinessUnitEnum.empty);   

//set all flush updates to false
intOrg01.setFlushUpdates(false);
user01.setFlushUpdates(false);

//add intOrg to user
user01.setInternalOrganization(intOrg01);
```

--- custom impl. for findDirty:

```
@Override
public int[] findDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,
  String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {

        /**
         * logic impl.
         */
        if (entity instanceof AbstractBO) {
            if (((AbstractBO) entity).isFlushUpdates()) {
                return null;
            } else {
                logger.info("Ignoring flush for object: " + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + ", "
                        + entity.toString());
                return new int[0];
            }
        }
    }   
   //flush entityManager
   //THIS triggers an insert of intOrg ! (no update to the User table)
   entityManager.flush();
```